# Separate Numbers and Letters

Tags: java, split, letters-and-numbers

Let's say I have a String that says `"Hello123"`, how can I separate them to become `s[0] = "Hello", s[1] = "123"`? I wish to use `s.split()` but I don't know what to put in the argument/parameter.

Comment: first, find a substring that is one of the characters 1-9, then split at that location.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regular expression:

```
String[] splitArray = subjectString.split(
    "(?x)                  # verbose regex mode on                    \n" +
    "(?<=                  # Assert that the previous character is... \n" +
    " \\p{L}               # a letter                                 \n" +
    ")                     # and                                      \n" +
    "(?=                   # that the next character is...            \n" +
    " \\p{N}               # a digit.                                 \n" +
    ")                     #                                          \n" +
    "|                     # Or                                       \n" +
    "(?<=\\p{N})(?=\\p{L}) # vice versa");
```

splits

```
psdfh123sdkfjhsdf349287
```

into

```
psdfh
123
sdkfjhsdf
349287
```