# Can I separate letters/numbers of a string and put into an array in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

Basically I'd like to take a string like:

```
"D1F21a"
```

And turn it into an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => D
    [1] => 1
    [2] => F
    [3] => 21
    [4] => a
)
```

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551985/separate-numbers-and-letters) but can't seem to successfully get it to work in PHP without getting Unknown modifier errors.

Comment: Is that string a hex number, or is that just coincidence?

Comment: what PHP version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to split the string at every number, capturing the numbers in the process:

```php
$arr = preg_split('/(\d+)/', 'D1F21a', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

would result in:

```
array(5) {
  [0] => string(1) "D"
  [1] => string(1) "1"
  [2] => string(1) "F"
  [3] => string(2) "21"
  [4] => string(1) "a"
}
```

Comment: Accepting this since it's the shortest alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The `\K` verb tells the engine to drop whatever it has matched so far from the match to be returned. Split the string.

```
\d+\K|\D+\K
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/hR7lS8/6)

OR get the matched group from index 1

sample code:

```
$re = "/(\\d+\\K|\\D+\\K)/";
$str = "D1F21a";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

---

You can split it with [**Lookahead and Lookbehind**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) from digit after non-digit and vice verse.

```
(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)
```

explanation:

```
\D  Non-Digit [^0-9]
\d  any digit [0-9]
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/hR7lS8/3)

Comment: Thanks! That works. Put into PHP: $out = preg_split('/(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)/',$in);

Answer (score 0):

The regexp that you linked works as well:

```
$regexp = '/(?<=\p{L})(?=\p{N})|(?<=\p{N})(?=\p{L})/';
$data = "D1F21a";
$matches = preg_split($regexp, $data);
var_dump($matches);
```